# Pre-processing data: difference between sklearn StandardScaler and scipy whiten

Tags: scikit-learn, scipy, cluster-analysis, sklearn-pandas, data-preprocessing

I'm trying to apply clustering analysis to some data and following some tutorials, and there are two options for normalize the data, the function StandardScaler and the function whiten.

What is the difference between both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The StandardScaler() performs Z-score normalization by removing the mean and dividing by the standard deviation. The whiten() does not remove the mean but just divides the instance by the standard deviation. I'd personally go for the StandardScaler(), because it allows for an easy `fit_transform` on the train set and `transform` on the test set to prevent spillage/leakage.

Below a proof of principle:

Load the packages

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.cluster.vq import whiten
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
```

Initialize a features array

```
features  = np.array([[1.9, 2.3, 1.7],
                      [1.5, 2.5, 2.2],
                      [0.8, 0.6, 1.7,]])
```

As an example, calculate the mean of the first column and the standard deviation of the first column

```
meancol1 = np.mean(features[:,0])
std_col1 = np.std(features[:,0])
```

Execute the whiten function

```
whit = whiten(features)
```

Initialize the standard scaler and fit_transform on the features

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
std_scaler = scaler.fit_transform(features)
```

Manually calculate the z-score of the first instance

```
z_score = (features[0,0] - meancol1) / std_col1
```

Manually perform the whiten function for the first instance

```
w_score = features[0,0]/std_col1
```

As you can see, the manual calculations correspond to their respective function outcomes.